# What is the difference between Lemma and Theorem in Coq

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I can't tell in which situations I should use `Theorem` over `Lemma` or the opposite. Is there any difference (despite syntactical) between this

```
Theorem l : 2 = 2.
  trivial.
Qed.
```

and this

```
Lemma l : 2 = 2.
  trivial.
Qed.
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference between `Theorem` and `Lemma` as far as the language is concerned. The reasons to choose one over another are purely psychological.
You can also use `Remark`, `Fact`, `Corollary`, `Proposition` according to the importance you attribute to the result. Here is the [relevant link](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#coq:cmd.theorem) in the Coq reference manual.

Some projects' code style guides only allow one keyword to be used for uniformity.  This might help reading source code and allow using simple grep-like tools to extract some statistics from it.

Comment: Actually, `Property` can also be used for the same purpose, but does not seem to be documented anywhere.